# New VBO bulk operation button not get translated

Tags: 7, commerce, views

VBO button not translated issue.

I have created a new VBO bulk operation using rules component.
[image]

This is the button:

[image]

In Rules I have written the translation for this rule, in the translate tab of the rule.

But the button in the view doesn't display translated.
:(

Too I tried to override a label in the view for this button, and translate this label with the translate view option, translating this field.

But the button doesn't translate too.

How could I translate my button?

Comment: Not sure if it would help/apply in this case, but maybe you want to check either of the options I suggested in my answer to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196492/how-to-translate-select-list-options-used-in-exposed-filters-of-a-view/196496#196496 ...

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a link below:-

http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views_bulk_operations!views_bulk_operations.api.php/function/hook_views_bulk_operations_form_alter/7

Here a function 
`function hook_views_bulk_operations_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $vbo) {
}` 
We can use this function and here we can actually do custom code for this particular action and set the label accordingly.

Would be able to answer more appropriately if you share some more details with your question that what you basically did.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav!.

I am trying to translate a new operation I have added to my vbo. 
This operation is available to add in my vbo because I created a rule component doing the action for the entity I am using in my vbo.

All this is normal and I did using drupal admin interface, no coding.

In my screenshots you can see it, and how the button for this operation is not translated.

Can you tell me more exactly what code do I add to force a title for this button?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: How could I know what is the name of the array form element to change in the code? Is there any tool to debug or display it?